# How to order descending by a field in a different model in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

[Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) is an example how to order descending:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
```

So we can use: `'-pub_date'`.
And another example how to order by a field in another model:

```
Entry.objects.order_by('blog__name', 'headline')
```

So we can use: `'blog__name'`.
How i can do both in one query? 'blog__-name' doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `'-blog__name'`.

Comment: That was fast answer! (i can't accept your answer yet, i will come back later here)